# How can I close the quickfix window and go back to the file I was editing

Tags: quickfix, tags, cscope

I use [gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags) and [gutentags-plus](https://github.com/skywind3000/gutentags_plus) for generating and managing tag files. When I use the key combinations setup by them ( cX usually ), it opens the relevant lines in a quickfix window and I can use :cnext etc for navigation. But how do I close them quickfix window and go back to the file I was editing after I have gone through the lines found in cscope?

PS: Actually I am using [global](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/global.html) instead of cscope but I guess on VIM side it should not matter.

Comment: I'm not sure what your PS means. However I think you're looking for `:cclose` [`:h :cclose`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acclose)?

Comment: Corrected and added a link to clarify. Sorry about that!

Comment: Ok I get it now, but my solution still stands: is `:cclose` the command you're looking for?

Comment: When in the quickfix window, `<C-w>c` (c like "close") will do, when in the 'main' window, `<C-w>o` (o like "only [this window]" or "[close] other [window]"). Assuming only two windows are open.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To close the quickfix window, you use `:cclose`, as @statox mentioned in the comments.

This won't affect which code buffer you're viewing, though. Vim doesn't distinguish between the buffer you were looking at originally and the buffers you navigated to via the quickfix, so to go back you are going to have to use Vim's regular buffer switching commands. If you know the name or number of the original buffer, `:b` is probably quickest.

If not, you could try mashing <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> to jump backwards through the jumplist till you reach the right buffer, or you might want to set up [some mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16084326/328936)* (or a plugin) for faster buffer navigation.

If you want something automated, how about adding something like following to your .vimrc?

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>gs mA:GscopeFind s <C-R><C-W><cr>
nnoremap <leader>b :cclose<CR>`A
```

The first mapping adapts your [current search mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19754/343) to first set an uppercase mark A and then continue with its original behaviour.

The second creates a new mapping that closes the quickfix and then returns to the marked position.

<sub>* Make sure you read as far down as the EDIT, because it's after that that the juicy details are included.</sub>

Comment: Or faster solution would be to create a new tab with the current buffer so that he can just close the tabpage with the quickfix window altogether and go back to the newly created tagpage. But he has to remember to do `<C-w>T` every time. Or maybe an autocmd trigger with `QuickFixCmdPost` etc. to open the quickfix window *after* creating a new tab? That could also work, right?

Comment: @klaus Not sure if you saw my edit with the new mappings? Your idea is good too, though!

Comment: No, you just edited it after I commented. That mapping makes more sense because of automation. Good stuff!

Comment: hmm I tried it my I just get a `Mark not set error`

Comment: Ok, this is the correct way to fix it but with one caveat that I list in my answer

Comment: @OsadaLakmal Ah okay. I don’t use gutentags_plus, and I interpreted your question as saying that `cX` was the mapping that opens the quickfix. Glad my answer helped you come up with a solution, though, and thanks for the accept!

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see how `:nmap cX mAcX` will work, since the `cX` in it can only call the same mapping again. (In other words, infinite recursion.) If defined after the original `cX` mapping, it will just overwrite it. Perhaps that part of the answer needs an update...?

Comment: @filbranden Yes, that bit is clearly completely wrong. Was I drunk when I wrote it? I'll update. Thanks!

Comment: @Rich I often ask myself the same question re-reading posts I wrote a few months back... Thanks for taking a fresh look at this one!

Comment: @filbranden What's particularly weird about this one, is not so much the recursive mapping--which could just be a brainfart--but the fact that I wrote an entire explanatory paragraph afterwards that was just utter rubbish!

Answer (score 0):

@klaus makes the correct suggestion to set a mark. However I needed to set it before the quick fix window appeared not while traversing the list. I am using [gutentags_plus](https://github.com/skywind3000/gutentags_plus) plugin to make cscope work with guten-tags plugin. So I just redefined Gscopefind command mappings from

```
noremap <silent> <leader>gs :GscopeFind s <C-R><C-W><cr>
```

to

```
noremap <silent> <leader>gs mA :GscopeFind s <C-R><C-W><cr>
```